# How to use multi SELECT in node RestAPI

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mysql-workbench

I'm working on a REST API in node with express. I trying to make a GET method which should return datas from my database.

My request is working perfectly on MySQL workbench. But when I put the exact same request from my node query I've got an error...

```sql
SELECT M.id,
       M.`expediteur`,
       M.`destinataire`,
       M.contenu,
       M.date

    FROM messages M
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT `expediteur`, max(id) as maxId
         FROM messages
         WHERE `destinataire` = "aaa@ccc.Co" OR `expediteur` = "aaa@ccc.Co"
         GROUP BY `expediteur`)T
    ON M.id = T.maxId
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

My node request :

```
connection.query(request, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    response.status(200).end(JSON.stringify(results))
})
```

Here is my error :

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MINNER JOIN    (SELECT `expediteur`, max(id) as maxId     FROM messages     WHER' at line 1",
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: 'SELECT M.id,   M.`expediteur`,   M.`destinataire`,   M.contenu,   M.dateFROM messages MINNER JOIN    (SELECT `expediteur`, max(id) as maxId     FROM messages     WHERE `destinataire` = "aaa@ccc.Co" OR `expediteur` = "aaa@ccc.Co"     GROUP BY `expediteur`)TON M.id = T.maxIdORDER BY date DESC'
```

After some test, it seems that the INNER JOIN is not accepted from my code, and the space is MINNER JOIN...

Thanks for your help :)